# How to get installation log (either from adb install or manual install)

Tags: installation, usb-debugging, logging, debug

The question is what to grep/filter?

```
adb logcat | grep what?
adb install file.apk
```

tried with `grep apk` and manual install, but it contains no useful information:

```
01-25 17:29:05.721  4241  6322 I ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///data/user_de/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/no_backup/package7763548981090696460.apk flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallInstalling (has extras)} from uid 10020, pid 24521
01-25 17:29:08.660  4241  5058 I ActivityManager: START u0 {dat=file:///data/user_de/0/com.google.android.packageinstaller/no_backup/package7763548981090696460.apk flg=0x2000000 cmp=com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.InstallFailed (has extras)} from uid 10020, pid 24521
```

tried with `grep apk` and `adb install` nothing captured (stuck), how can i know what part causes the installation failure?

Comment: @Robert whoa nice, that shows the real problem `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]`, btw you can make your comment as an answer, i'll upvote and mark it.

Comment: Most likely this means your device is older and supports only ARMv7 (ARM 32bit) or has an x86 cpu but the APK file requires an ARMv8 (ARM 64bit) system. In that case you can only search for a different APK file that supports the CPU type of your device (BTW: as I always say you should always write the device name and vendor into the question when posting a question here).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes errors are getting lost when using adb. Effectively `adb install` does nothing more than uploading the apk file to the the device and then executing the command `pm install <file.apk>`.

Therefore in case of problems you can perform those steps manually and see the complete log of the package manager `pm` when installing the apk file.

Therefore I would suggest doing the following:

1. Upload the apk file to your device (e.g. via `adb push`, MTP, direct download to the device, ...)
2. Open an adb shell by executing `adb shell`
3. Install the apk file:  `pm install <path_to_the_apk_file_on_the_device.apk>`

Then you should get the most details log and all (error) messages.